# Sorting array of arrays on column

Tags: ruby

I have an array of arrays like this:

```
customers = [[439, "Customer A", 60800.0], [8, "Customer B", 264509.0], [546, "Customer C", 17900.0]]
```

How can I sort this on the 3rd column (the turnover), from high to low?

Comment: `customers.sort_by { |s| -s.last }`

Comment: @sagarpandya82, from high to low

Comment: @Ilya thanks, fixed

Comment: @sagarpandya82, also `customers.sort_by { |s| -s[-1] }` :D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `Enumerable#sort_by`:

```
customers.sort_by { |e| -e[2] }
=> [[8, "Customer B", 264509.0],
    [439, "Customer A", 60800.0],
    [546, "Customer C", 17900.0]]
```

Comment: You could also decompose the array: `customers.sort_by { |*, t| -t }`

Comment: @sagarpandya82, it's a splat operator: `*a, b = [1, 2, 3]`. `a` is [1, 2] `b` is 3.

Comment: @sagarpandya82 [Array Decomposition](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/doc/syntax/assignment_rdoc.html#label-Array+Decomposition)

Answer (score 0):

I would use [Array#sort](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Array.html#method-i-sort) and use a block with it, which gets two elements they will be compared. I like these expressive notation.

Each of these elements is one of the inner arrays and I compare the third element (index is 2) of these arrays. `y[2] <=> x[2]` meens descending order and `x[2] <=> y[2]` meens ascending order. Note that all inner arrays need the third element. Otherwise you will get unexpected results.

```
customers.sort{|x,y| y[2] <=> x[2]}
# => [[8, "Customer B", 264509.0], [439, "Customer A", 60800.0], [546, "Customer C", 17900.0]]
```

Comment: I think `sort_by` is much clearer. For this example, the difference between `y[2] <=> x[2]` and `x[2] <=> y[2]` might not be very visible.